# How to Save Filters with PNG in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, png

I have created a graphic with multiple layers in Inkscape. One of the layers is some text. I have applied a drop shadow filter to the text. When I save the file as PNG, the drop shadow is not saved. I have also tried applying a gaussian blur to the text layer and to the text layer after converting it to an object. The blur is not applied.

How can I save the file as PNG with the drop shadow intact?

Comment: I'm having this same issue (or at least a similar one). I'm trying to export a selection with an inner shadow filter, and it quite strangely only exports part of the inner shadow (the corners, but not the sides (on a box with rounded corners). It seems like I shouldn't be having this problem when "Hide all except selected" is not checked. I'm going to try to find a workaround, but this is kind of annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably not exporting the whole image. I think by default Inkscape exports only what you have currently selected. So when you export, make sure you have everything you want selected, or choose "Page" in the export type.

Answer (score 1):

works here with Inkscape 0.47 r22583 (Apr  4 2010)
regardless of whether I use "page" or "selection" when exporting to bitmap. Which version do you use ?

(checked with `display` command of the Image Magick package, if that matters)

Comment: im using Inkscape 0.48.0 r9654, problem was i didn't choose page when exporting, i was using save as...